# Trying and failing to place looped content within a div

Tags: php, mysql, forms, dynamic, html

Basically here is the scenario:

I am trying to generate a test from a database. Each test has many questions(items) each item is of a certain type (multi-choice etc), each question has multiple answers attached to it.

(I'm not looking for somebody to tell me im going about it all wrong)

I currently, loop through my query results and print out every question there. Within that loop I execute a function (present_question) for every question. Within this function is a switch case, which identifies the item type. Within each case, I run another loop to print out all the answers attached to that question.

What I am trying to do, is insert each question into a unique `<div>` so that I toggle the display etc between each question as they select a button for each so 1,2,3,4 etc.

However, it would appear I am struggling with this. My questions all print out, however It appears they are not within individual `<divs>` as I  tried testing it by changing some attributes of the class and its doing nothing. :(

Here is the main code covering the whole procedure:

**main loop:**

```
//loop through every question present in query results and run function to present the different question structures
    while ($qs = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_questions))
    {
        $type = $qs['item_type'];
        $item_id = $qs['item_id'];
        $question = $qs['question_text'];

        echo "<div class='q_center' id='q_$q_num'>";  // insert each question into its own div
        echo "<h2>Question No.$q_num </h2><br>";
        echo "$question <br>";      // print out actual question
        present_question($item_id, $type);
        $q_num ++;
    }
```

**present_question function**

```
function present_question($ID, $type){
    // grab all the answers attached to the question
    $get_answers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers_tb WHERE item_id='$ID'");

    echo "<form>";
    // switch for different structured questions. (switched by question type)   
    switch ($type)
    {
    case "1":
    multi_choice($get_answers); // just working on this type at the moment
    break;
    case "2":
    echo "this type hasnt been done yet";
    break;
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</form>";
    return;
}
```

**function for multiple choice type**

```
function multi_choice($get_answers){
    while ($answers = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_answers))
        {
            $as = $answers['text_value'];
            echo "<input type='radio' name='1' value='$as'>$as<hr />";
        }
    return;
}
```

hopefully you guys can help me.

I am a beginner, so I do apologise if my code is an abomination :D

thanks,

Comment: Could you JOIN all your queries into one? So each row would have all the questions and answers? Maybe listing the data and table structure would help

Comment: after playing around, the problem is echo "<div class='q_center' id='q_$q_num'>"; the div is working, but the class attributes arent being applied. :S

Answer (score 0):

rough version (untested)

```
$i = 0; //declares the counter $i
    //loop through every question present in query results and run function to present the different question structures
        while ($qs = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_questions))
        {
            $type = $qs['item_type'];
            $item_id = $qs['item_id'];
            $question = $qs['question_text'];

$i++; // adds 1 to $i

        echo "<div class='q_center' id='q_$q_num'>";  // insert each question into its own div
        echo "<h2>Question No.$q_num </h2><br>";
echo "<div class=question" .$i. ">"; //appends $i to the div name creating question[$i]
        echo "$question <br>";      // print out actual question
echo "</div>";
        present_question($item_id, $type);
        $q_num ++;
    }
```

should make div's named question1, question2, etc

Comment: that wouldn work, because none of the options (radio inputs) etc would be within that div. and surely I want to set the div with an id, because later i am gna want to toggle it with javascript, no?

Comment: there we go, re edited it and through in some comments @buymypies

Comment: sorry i probs didnt make it clear enough, but the question is the actualy question string  aswell as the options etc. so all within the div.

Comment: apologies, didn't thoroughly read it too well, will have a look, what are your divs coming out named as?

Comment: You could try declaring $q_num = 0; before your main loop, if still no luck change your div to   echo "<div class='q_center' id='q_" .$q_num."'>";   @buymypies